Date Format with PHP using Datetime
I have two dates I need to show it in format
29th and 30th November 2024
or
28th to 30th November 2024
or 
28th October to 30th November 2024
or
30th November and 1st December2024

What I tried so for is the code below.
                $date1 = new DateTime('2024-09-29');
                $month1 = $date1->format('m');
                $date2 = new DateTime('2024-09-30');
                $month2 = $date2->format('m');
                $interval = $date1->diff($date2);
                if($month1 == $month2){
                    if($interval->days == 1){
                        $result_date = getDayWithSuffix($date1);
                        $result_date .= ' and ';
                        $result_date .= getDayWithSuffix($date2);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('Y');
                    } else {
                        $result_date = getDayWithSuffix($date1);
                        $result_date .= ' to ';
                        $result_date .= getDayWithSuffix($date2);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('Y');
                    }
                } else {
                    if($interval->days == 1){
                        $result_date = getDayWithSuffix($date1);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' and ';
                        $result_date .= getDayWithSuffix($date2);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date2->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('Y');
                    } else {
                        $result_date = getDayWithSuffix($date1);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' to ';
                        $result_date .= getDayWithSuffix($date2);
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date2->format('F');
                        $result_date .= ' '.$date1->format('Y');
                    }
                }

Is there a better way to achieve this?

In case you are asking to improve an existing working code, it;s better suitable in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

define "better". What issue do you have with this code exactly?

The getDayWithSuffix function seems a bit superfluous - ->format('jS') can get you day number and suffix directly.

You could clean it up a bit to make it neater, but the general approach is fine I think.
Something like:
$date1 = new DateTime('2024-09-29');
$date2 = new DateTime('2024-09-30');

$month1 = $date1->format('m');
$month2 = $date2->format('m');
$year = $date1->format('Y');
$interval = $date1->diff($date2);

// Common part of the date formatting
$day1 = $date1->format('jS');
$day2 = $date2->format('jS');
$month1Name = $date1->format('F');
$month2Name = $date2->format('F');

// Build the result based on the month comparison and day difference
if ($month1 == $month2) {
    // Same month
    $result_date = $interval->days == 1 
        ? "$day1 and $day2 $month1Name $year" 
        : "$day1 to $day2 $month1Name $year";
} else {
    // Different months
    $result_date = $interval->days == 1 
        ? "$day1 $month1Name and $day2 $month2Name $year" 
        : "$day1 $month1Name to $day2 $month2Name $year";
}

// Output result
echo $result_date;

